# Dealing with php (explode)

Tags: php, mysql

I am in progress of creating a database that has 4 columns, "Type", "Compatible", "StockLevel", "Cost".

The type may be "Battery" with the compatible field being the ID of the devices that this battery works with.. for example "1, 4, 9".

What I need my PHP to do is query the database for all "Types" that include $_POST[compatible] in the "Compatible" row. Of course this isn't as simple as IF X = X, because we first need to (php) explode the Compatible field.

My head hurts and I'm still trying to find a solution but I will paste my code and hope that one of you can provide some help.

```
IF ($_POST["printer"]) {

    $printerinfo_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM printers WHERE ID LIKE '$_POST[printer]'");
    $printerinfo_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($printerinfo_query);

    echo ("<H5>".$printerinfo_result["Model"]."</H5>");
    echo "".$printerinfo_result["Description"]."";

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $cartridge_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cartridges");
    $cartridge_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($cartridge_query);


    $explode = $cartridge_result["Compatible"];
    $explodedata = explode(", ", $explode);
    $explode_count = count($explodedata);
    $explode_count_dec = count($explodedata);
    $explode_number = "0"; // Re-creates $explodedata[0], [1], [2] etc.. using $explodedata[$explode_number] in the loop!

    echo ("<P>Select a cartridge type &mdash;</P>");

    echo "<form action='index.php?page=printeradv' method='POST'>";


      while ($explode_count_dec > "0"):

        $while_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cartridges WHERE ID LIKE '$explodedata[$explode_number]'");
        $while_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($while_query);

        echo "<input type='radio' value='".$explodedata[$explode_number]."' name='cartridge' />".$while_result["Type"]." <BR /> ";

        ++$explode_number;
        --$explode_count_dec;
      endwhile;

    echo "<input type='submit' value='Select model' />";
    echo "</form>";

}
```

Comment: You might also want to look at rejigging the database design, so that the information currently in the compatible field goes into a separate table - the design you've got now will work for a handful of items, but once you've got a few dozen items in there, maintaining it will be increasingly difficult.

Comment: I know this sounds silly but I'm planning on editing this data through an admin panel, and as such won't need to maintain it directly. Although, how would you suggest I make my database? I have 2 tables, 'Batteries' and 'Watches'. Watches has ID, Name, Description. The batteries table (compatible field) then includes the ID of watches that this battery is compatible with. Is that understandable?

Comment: See Surreal Dreams' post below for what to do. The problem with putting all the data in a comma separated list is that if you've defined the field as (say) 250 characters, you'll run out of space as you add extra items; if you put the information into a separate table, you can add as much as you need to.

Comment: Ah that's no problem, there will be a max of 3-4 (comma separated lists)

Comment: You say that now... Just wait til people start using it, and its scope grows beyond what you're currently expecting. It's best to build this sort of thing in from the start, otherwise you'll have a much trickier job to add it in six months from now.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do use `explode()` and I don't know why you're using LIKE when you're not actually using wild characters.

You can directly search with `$cartridge_result['Compatible']`, like this:

```
... WHERE ID IN('.$cartridge_result['Compatible'].')'
```

Comment: That's interesting, can you explain further? I need to show the name of each "Type" that includes $_POST[compatible] within the "Compatible" field.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add an additional relation table to relate your batteries to devices.  It's a very simple table:

> relationid | batteryId | deviceId

This allows you to do simple queries to get all compatible batteries *or* devices.  This is a standard practice for managing a many to many relationship such as this.  The end result is that you can run a single query to determine compatibility and your processing afterwards in PHP is minimal.